# Como obter o indexOf de uma lista preenchida no change de um select usando o ng-options do angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Como faço para obter o **indexOf** de um item selecionado no meu **select**?

**Html**

```
<div class="row container">
    <div class="col s12 ">
        <h4>Cadastrar Pedido</h4>
    </div>
    <form class="" name="formulario">
         <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s6 m6 l6">
                <i class="material-icons prefix">store</i>
                <select ng-controller="ListaProdutos"
                        ng-model="pedido.ProdutoId"
                        ng-options="prod.Id as prod.NomeProduto for prod in ListaProdutos"
                        ng-change="MostraQuantidade(ListaProdutos.indexOf(prod))" material-select>
                    <option value="">Selecione um produto</option>
                </select>
                <label for="inputLoja">Produto</label>
            </div>

            <div class="input-field col s2 m2 l2">
                <i class="material-icons prefix">store</i>
                <input id="inputQtd" type="number" class="validate" name="Qtd" ng-model="pedido.Qtd" min="0" max="">
                <label for="inputLoja">Qua</label>
            </div>
            <div class="input-field col s2 m2 l2">
                <a class="btn-floating btn-large waves-effect waves-light red"><i class="material-icons">add</i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
angular.module("modaFeminina").controller("PedidoController", function ($scope, $http, $base64) {

    $scope.pedido = {}

    $scope.submeter = function () {
        var teste = $scope.pedido;
    }


}).controller("ListaProdutos", function ($scope, $http) {

    $scope.ListaProdutos = [];

    $http.get("/Produto/Listar").success(function (produtos) {
        $scope.ListaProdutos = produtos;
    })
    .error(function () {

    });

    $scope.MostraQuantidade = function (value) {

        var index = value;

    }
});
```

Comment: Tente isto: `ListaProdutos.indexOf(pedido.ProdutoId)`

Comment: @bfavaretto ja tentei ele me retorna -1 na minha função.

Answer (score 0):

Dentro do ng-options você deve incluir o indexOf com o valor do seu array 
**exempo**  `ng-options="produtos.indexOf(prod) as prod.NomeProduto for prod in produtos"` feito isso o valor do ng-model se torna o index do array

Segue o código que montei espero ter ajudado

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="ctrl">   
     <select 
                        ng-model="ProdutoId"
                        ng-options="produtos.indexOf(prod) as prod.NomeProduto for prod in produtos"
                        ng-change="MostraQuantidade(ProdutoId)" material-select>
                    <option value="">Selecione um produto</option>
      </select>  
</div>

<script>
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('ctrl', function($scope) {

   $scope.produtos = [
        {Id: 1, NomeProduto: 'produto1'},
        {Id:2 , NomeProduto:'produto2'}
    ];

    $scope.MostraQuantidade = function (index) {
        console.log(index);
    }
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Mas dessa forma eu estarei armazenando o Index da minha lista no meu value do select, eu queria mandar o index somente no evento change e armazenar o id no value do select